# Delphi internal error code: Delphi XE6 [dcc64 Fatal Error] .pas(): F2084 Internal Error: AV08F046D5-R00000000-0

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6

Does anyone know what this is:

> Delphi XE6 [dcc64 Fatal Error] .pas(): F2084 Internal Error: AV08F046D5-R00000000-0

I get it if I try to compile a project in the project group (which includes a design time library, a non-visual library, and an executable).

A build all on the project group makes it go away but I am concerned about what it might indicate, if anything...

The application has to be Win64 compatible, but the libraries have to compile in Win32. Is it just that dcc64 is having trouble with the 32 bit components - or something else in my options perhaps?

Comment: Did you remove your unit name for the sake of this question, or is the actual error showing just `.pas`?

Comment: I removed the unit name

Comment: It is part of a secured nomenclature.

Answer (score 3):

That is an internal compiler error. This is a compiler bug. The reported code means something to Embarcadero, and can be used to search to check if others have the same issue. Typically such errors are caused by very specific combinations of code and compiler options. It is not likely that anyone will be able to diagnose the cause of the error without such information.

If you can't find any other report of this issue, submit a QC report. The report needs to include minimal steps to reproduce. That means a short but complete program.